# Как использовать локальную базу данных?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

Создаю проект, формы и всю реализацию. В каждой форме по коннект-строке и эта строка такая:[image: строкаконнекта].
При компиляции все работает только у меня, т.к путь в строке стоит мой собственный, а то есть на других устройствах моя программа работать не будет. Чтобы заработало на других устройствах мне приходится устанавливать туда Visual Studio и менять код этой строки.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А программу вы на клиентские компьютеры с исходными кодами копируете тоже?

Comment: пишу лабу. да тоже в архив заливаю туда все. Просто я что-то не туда свернул и не так начал все делать.

Comment: MSSQLLocalDb - это версия MS SQL Server для разработчиков, еще разик - для разработчиков. Она не должна использоваться на клиентских рабочих местах и тем более как рабочая СУБД. Вам надо либо использовать клиент-серверную архитектуру, т.е. установить где-то SQL Server, либо использовать именно локальную БД типа SQLite. Строку подключения нужно вычитывать из конфигурационного файла программы, который можно редактировать в блокноте, а не ставить для этого VS.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд вам можно поступить следующим способом:

1. Добавить файл с БД в проект, в какую-нибудь папку, например TestDataBase. 
   Пусть файл будет mydb.mdf.

[image: Скриншот структуры проекта]

2. Перейти в свойства файла и установить подчеркнутые параметры:

[image: Свойства файла в проекте]

После этого при компиляции ваш файл будет находиться в папке проекта:

`\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug\DataBaseTest\mydb.mdf` (Подпапки bin зависят от параметров сборки).

Из кода же вы будете обращаться примерно так (после атрибутов, где вы писали С:\...)

```
\DataBaseTest\mydb.mdf
```

Это поможет вам решить проблему быстро и в лоб. Однако можно использовать и лучшие решения...

p.s. Учитывая, что это лабораторная работа и исходные коды в любом случае необходимо предоставить и желательно запустить при преподавателе, то решение канает. А если это разработка заказная, то конечно так не пойдет.

p.p.s. Ну и конечно оно достаточно топорное. :)